# Vue storybook doesn't render component initially

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, storybook

The storybook works well, except it doesn't "render" the component initially.

- You can see in the screenshot that the component-template gets used somehow, or else the storybook wouldn't know the basic layout of the component.
- You can also see that the actions get called correctly already.
- The only real issue I can see is that at first storybook tries to mutate every prop the component has. Don't know why.
- This error occurs in javaScript and typeScript files.
- Stories that don't require a vue-component (only change styles etc.) seem to work correctly.

After I change any value using the controls everything renders correctly.

[image]

Here's the story for my shortest component:

```
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions";
import { ArgTypes, Meta, Story } from "@storybook/vue/types-6-0";
import { icons } from "../components/iconLoader";
import TsetButton from "../components/TsetButton.vue";

const argTypes = {
  size: {
    table: { disable: true },
  },
  type: {
    table: { disable: true },
  },
  iconLeft: {
    control: { type: "select" },
    options: Object.keys(icons),
  },
  iconRight: {
    control: { type: "select" },
    options: Object.keys(icons),
  },
  iconOnly: {
    control: { type: "select" },
    options: Object.keys(icons),
  },
  label: {
    control: { type: "text" },
  },
} as ArgTypes;

export default {
  title: "Tset/Components/TsetButton",
  component: TsetButton,
  // More on argTypes: https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/api/argtypes
  argTypes,
} as Meta;

const DefaultButton: Story = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  components: {
    TsetButton,
  },
  template: `
        <TsetButton
          v-bind="$props"
          type="primary"
          @click="onClick"
          @hoverStart="onHoverStart"
          @hoverEnd="onHoverEnd"
          size="default"
        />
    `,
  methods: {
    onClick: action("clicked"),
    onHoverStart: action("Hover Start"),
    onHoverEnd: action("Hover End"),
  },
});

export const Default = DefaultButton.bind({});
Default.args = {
  label: "Button",
  tooltip: "Tooltip",
};
```

And here's the component minus the style:

```
<template>
  <div v-tooltip="tooltipState">
    <button
      :class="[
        {
          'button-primary': isPrimary,
          'button-secondary': isSecondary,
          'button-ghost': isGhost,
          'button-tertiary': isTertiary,
          'button-loading': isLoading,
          'h-40 px-14 py-8': size === 'default',
          'h-32 px-16 py-8': size === 'small',
        },
        'flex items-center m-10',
      ]"
      :disabled="isDisabled"
      @click="onClick"
      @mouseover="onHoverStart"
      @mouseleave="onHoverEnd"
    >
      <TsetIcon
        :class="[
          {
            'h-20 w-20': size === 'default',
            'h-16 w-16': size === 'small',
          },
        ]"
        class="mr-11"
        :is="iconLeft"
        v-if="!iconOnly"
      />
      <TsetIcon
        :class="[
          {
            'h-20 w-20': size === 'default',
            'h-16 w-16': size === 'small',
          },
        ]"
        :is="iconOnly"
      />
      <template v-if="isLoading"> ... </template>
      <div
        v-if="!iconOnly && !isLoading"
        :class="[
          {
            'text-14': size === 'default',
            'text-12': size === 'small',
          },
        ]"
      >
        {{ label }}
      </div>
      <TsetIcon
        :class="[
          {
            'h-20 w-20': size === 'default',
            'h-16 w-16': size === 'small',
          },
        ]"
        class="ml-13"
        :is="iconRight"
        v-if="!iconOnly"
      />
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export type ButtonType = "primary" | "secondary" | "tertiary" | "ghost";
export type ButtonSize = "default" | "small";
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
import VTooltip from "v-tooltip";
Vue.use(VTooltip);

@Component({
  name: "TsetButton",
})
export default class Button extends Vue {
  @Prop()
  private readonly type!: ButtonType;
  @Prop()
  private readonly size!: ButtonSize;
  @Prop()
  private readonly isDisabled!: boolean;
  @Prop()
  private readonly isLoading!: boolean;
  @Prop()
  private readonly iconLeft: string | null = null;
  @Prop()
  private readonly iconRight: string | null = null;
  @Prop()
  private readonly iconOnly: string | null = null;
  @Prop()
  private readonly label!: string;
  @Prop()
  private readonly tooltip!: string;
  @Prop()
  private readonly disabledTooltip!: string;

  get tooltipState() {
    if (this.tooltip) {
      return this.tooltip;
    } else if (this.disabledTooltip) {
      return this.disabledTooltip;
    } else {
      return this.label;
    }
  }

  get isPrimary(): boolean {
    return this.type === "primary";
  }

  get isSecondary(): boolean {
    return this.type === "secondary";
  }

  get isTertiary(): boolean {
    return this.type === "tertiary";
  }

  get isGhost(): boolean {
    return this.type === "ghost";
  }

  onClick(): void {
    if (!this.isLoading && !this.isDisabled) this.$emit("click");
  }
  onHoverStart(): void {
    if (!this.isLoading && !this.isDisabled) this.$emit("hoverStart");
  }
  onHoverEnd(): void {
    if (!this.isLoading && !this.isDisabled) this.$emit("hoverEnd");
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding storybook with `vue add storybook` to a working project which fits our needs and then simply removing all the components, basically creating what I would get if I set it up correctly.

So if you have a similar issue, maybe going that route would be worth a try.